# what is the VAS exactly? is it specialy for communication?

Tags: gamekit, telecommunication

can I say that some value added services in a mobile game or application are VAS?
I have a challenge with myself because i heard that VAS is specialy for the communication services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VAS is commonly used in the telecom industry, it's true.
But it is a vague term, that can be used by anyone - see the [Wikipedia page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value-added_service) .  There's no legal meaning to these words.

I think you can use it if you have added value to something that is generally accepted as an industry standard, or a necessary service.